# Scala string manipulation

Tags: string, scala, for-loop

I have the following Scala code :

```
val res = for {
  i <- 0 to 3
  j <- 0 to 3
  if (similarity(z(i),z(j)) < threshold) && (i<=j)
} yield z(j)
```

z here represents `Array[String]` and `similarity(z(i),z(j))` calculates similarity between two strings.

This problems works like that similarity is calculated between 1st string and all the other strings and then similarity is calculated between 2nd string and all other strings except for first and then similarity for 3rd string and so on.

My requirement is that if 1st string matches with 3rd, 4th and 8th string, then
all these 3 strings shouldn't participate in loops further and loop should jump to 2nd string, then 5th string, 6th string and so on.

I am stuck at this step and don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: I'm confused-- is this a question about string manipulation?  Because strings are immutable in Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am presuming that your intent is to keep the first String of two similar Strings (eg. if 1st String is too similar to 3rd, 4th, and 8th Strings, keep only the 1st String [out of these similar strings]).

I have a couple of ways to do this. They both work, in a sense, in reverse: for each String, if it is too similar to any later Strings, then that current String is filtered out (not the later Strings). If you first reverse the input data before applying this process, you will find that the desired outcome is produced (although in the first solution below the resulting list is itself reversed - so you can just reverse it again, if order is important):

1st way (likely easier to understand):

```
def filterStrings(z: Array[String]) = {
  val revz = z.reverse
  val filtered = for {
    i <- 0 to revz.length if !revz.drop(i+1).exists(zz => similarity(zz, revz(i)) < threshold)
  } yield revz(i)
  filtered.reverse // re-reverses output if order is important
}
```

The 'drop' call is to ensure that each String is only checked against later Strings.

2nd option (fully functional, but harder to follow):

```
val filtered = z.reverse.foldLeft((List.empty[String],z.reverse)) { case ((acc, zt), zz) => 
  (if (zt.tail.exists(tt => similarity(tt, zz) < threshold)) acc else zz :: acc, zt.tail) 
}._1
```

I'll try to explain what is going on here (in case you - or any readers - aren't use to following folds):

This uses a fold over the reversed input data, starting from the empty String (to accumulate results) and the (reverse of the) remaining input data (to compare against - I labeled it `zt` for "z-tail").

The fold then cycles through the data, checking each entry against the tail of the remaining data (so it doesn't get compared to itself or any earlier entry)

If there is a match, just the existing accumulator (labelled `acc`) will be allowed through, otherwise, add the current entry (`zz`) to the accumulator. This updated accumulator is paired with the tail of the "remaining" Strings (`zt.tail`), to ensure a reducing set to compare against.

Finally, we end up with a pair of lists: the required remaining Strings, and an empty list (no Strings left to compare against), so we take the first of these as our result.

Comment: What should be done if I have to keep all the strings similar in one set after the first iteration, then after second iteration I should have the second set of similar strings and so on? @Shadowlands

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to loop through the elements of the array, comparing each element to later elements, and removing ones that are too similar as you go.

You can't (easily) do this within a simple loop. You'd need to keep track of which items had been filtered out, which would require another array of booleans, which you update and test against as you go. It's not a bad approach and is efficient, but it's not pretty or functional.

So you need to use a recursive function, and this kind of thing is best done using an immutable data structure, so let's stick to `List`.

```
def removeSimilar(xs: List[String]): List[String] = xs match {
  case Nil     => Nil
  case y :: ys => y :: removeSimilar(ys filter {x => similarity(y, x) < threshold})
}
```

It's a simple-recursive function. Not much to explain: if `xs` is empty, it returns the empty list, else it adds the head of the list to the function applied to the filtered tail.